# Differential equation for a probability density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-process

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ be a Markov process with state space in $[0,1]$ and generator $L$ defined on functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ as follows
\begin{align}
Lf(x)=\int_0^1J(x,y)(f(y)-f(x))dx,
\end{align}
where $J:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb R$ is a smooth and symmetric function such that $\int_0^1 J(x,y)dy=1$.

I would like to prove that $P(X_t\leq x)=\int_0^xu_t(y)dy$ where
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}u_t(x)=\int_0^1J(x,y)(u_t(y)-u_t(x))dy.
\end{align}
Is this a consequence of the fact that I know explicitly the generator? Could the Kolmogorov equations help me in some way? Do I need to prove something else like the absolutely continuity of the measure?

Thank you

Comment: You're trying to get the one-dimensional distribution of the process. You track the evolution of this by using the forward Kolmogorov equation (possibly in a suitable weak sense if the distribution isn't nice enough).

Comment: How can I know if the distribution is nice enough? The generator should tell me everything about the distribution of my process or not?

Comment: The generator and the initial condition give all the information that you need. But the forward Kolmogorov equation doesn't always have strong solutions. Imagine for example an equation with generator $\partial_x$ and an initial distribution of a point mass.

Comment: Sorry, If I prove that there exists a unique solution of the equation I have written upstairs it automatically implies that the forward Kolmogorov equation has a strong solution?

Comment: No, because the forward Kolmogorov equation is formally an equation for the density, not the CDF. It still makes sense in a weak sense when no density exists, however.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in this argument. If the forward Kolmogorov equation is an equation for the density it means that it is an equation for the function $u_t(x)$ that I defined above, is that correct?

Comment: That's right, sorry, I wasn't paying careful enough attention to your notation.

Comment: Ok, Thank you! So If I prove that the solution of the equation above exists and is unique is finished, in the sense that I can conclude that my Markov process has a density function $u_t(x)$ which satisfies that equation? I have just one doubt, I don't need to prove that my measure $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue?